# What are the general guidelines for submitting feature request?

Tags: discussion

When someone wants to request a feature, how should they go about asking it?

Answer (score 6):

You should ask a question on meta. The question should:

- have a title that includes a very short description of the request
- include a description of what the feature is
- argue for *why* the feature is needed
- be tagged with [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

From the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)  [tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/feature-request/info):

> Your question should contain the details of your proposal, including a justification of why the new feature is needed and/or how it can improve the community. Basically, [prove](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188) to the administration that they should spend time developing your feature.

If your feature request only pertains to a particular site, make sure you post the question on that site's meta, not here on Meta.SE.

Comment: Also note that as these sites already exist for some years a lot of feature requests are already asked and [tag:status-declined]. Use the [search](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfeature-request%5D+voting) feature of the site to get informed about related if not duplicate requests.